# glassfish and netbeans, I can't execute the asadmin command

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, glassfish-3, netbeans-7, asadmin

I use Netbeans 7.1 and during its installation I setted up a glassfish server 3.1.
I always lauch the server trough the IDE facility, but now I'm trying to do it trough the shell, but the asadmin command is not supported, where i wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Windows` you have navigate to the `bin` directory of glassfish. For e.g.: My glassfish is installed into: `C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-3.1.2\bin`. If I open the `cmd`  I need to run: `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-3.1.2\bin` and then `asadmin start-domain domain1`. Then it works.

Comment: You are welcome :) You can accept the answers that you helped you solve your issues.